# Why am I getting a random offset voltage?

Tags: circuit-design, coupling

I have query about the following circuit which is an enable for a regulator.

[image]

This is on a 2 layer PCB. OUT goes to a Schmidt Triggered Inverter to the clock on a D-Type Flip Flop, where the output from the flipflop feeds via an inverter back into the input of the flipflop. It is used to toggle a switching regulator on/off with a push button and delay.

The 5v supplied to this section of the circuit (and the inverter and flipflop) is separately generated with a tiny 100ma LDO, so this circuit is always on. The only connection to the rest of the circuit is the OUT to the input of the inverter and the GND.

When the button is pushed there is around 1 second delay before the voltage reaches the inverters negative threshold, which then clocks the Dtype Flop Flop.

My problem is, when the regulator is on, and I have a load connected (0.5amps ~ 5v), if I hold the button down, I see an offset voltage at OUT of around 500mv, this changes based on the load I put on the switching regulator.

What is even more strange is the following options 'fix' the problem, or at least reduce this offset voltage by half or more - but I have zero idea why.

- A random bit of 24AWG wire floating in the air on A
- removing the diode (but it means the 'reset' after releasing the button is gone)
- a (randomly picked) 1k resistor right after D1.
- a (randomly picked) 1k resistor between C6 and GND.
- cutting the trace by the switch and rejoining it with a small loop of wire (this is on another board that has the power input and is connected via a FFC)

I assume something must be coupling to OUT to cause it to be 500mv when the button is pressed and the Switching Regulator is on with a load?

And the 100k resistor is perhaps too much? so that trace is susceptible to coupling to something else in the circuit?

But I cannot see how small loops of wire, or random wires in the air seem to solve this, especially as they are on what should be GND when the switch is pressed.

Any suggestions would be great.

Edit:

Just to add to this, the FCC cable pins are

**1** GND

**2-8** 20V

**9** **SWITCH** <--

**10-11** GND

**12-20** SIGNAL/GND alternating

Interestingly, I cut the **switch** traces to the FFC at both ends, and repurposed the next signal trace along with some tiny jumper wires and this works as expected, goes to about 10mv when the switch is pressed.

This leads me to believe it has to be something to do with having this switch trace being sandwiched between 20V and GND ? rather then a GND either side like all of the other signal traces?

I should note I have multiple boards, multiple FFC cables and this is same across all of them.

The other thing that solves this problem is running the switch wire separately. If I leave the FFC cable in as well as the jumper wire, its at 500mv when the button is pressed and the load is on, if I cut the traces to the FCC and just leave the jumper wire, it works as expected.

Comment: Half a circuit drawn, half a circuit in words = bad schematic in my book.

Comment: @Andyaka This is everything, apart from putting on an LDO for the power source and the inverter and flipflops, but OUT just goes into the inveter.. the rest is all working.

Comment: When I experience strange behavior like this it is often caused by poor grounding.

Comment: Run 20 ga wire between the ground connection of the cap and the ground connection of the switch. See what you get.

Comment: IN theory the logic is practical and works, in practice it becomes illogical because the traces are now  lossy and inductive while you have yet to define how your scope is connected to ground and if all grounds are still 0V. Show your layout

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 Scope is connected across the capacitor, with some small wires. checking across C6 or R2 with a multimeter also shows this 0.5v when the switch is depressed and the load is running

Comment: Mysterious operation and offsets sounds like a voltage regulator oscillating, because it's missing input or output capacitors.

Comment: @Neil_UK I have updated the question with some interesting findings/fix - the regulator seems pretty solid on the scope. No oscillation.

Comment: I'm guessing a ground loop is picking up EMI from the switching regulator, which then is rectified by the diode and charges the capacitor. Can you show us the PCB layout and a photo of the board?

Comment: Thanks @BruceAbbott - it looks like this is exactly the problem.